# Is there a free online Canadian English Dictionary?

Tags: support, online-resources

All Canadian English dictionaries appear to be under a paywall *model*.

Can anybody help?

Comment: The free online dictionaries I'm familiar with include meanings from multiple dialects. For example, the AHD includes a "chiefly British" sense *bonnet* for the hood of a car, and has entries for *billabong* and *loonie*; OALD has the Canadian and Australian uses of *washroom* and *drongo*; Collins includes the Canadian senses of *keener* and *chesterfield* and the antipodean uses of *swag* and *bushranger*. What would an exclusively Canadian dictionary provide?

Comment: @choster - well, someone took the pain to make a dedicated dictionary for Canadian English. https://www.oxfordreference.com/view/10.1093/acref/9780195418163.001.0001/acref-9780195418163

Comment: @choster - and more.. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Canadian_English_dictionaries

Comment: I'm not disputing their existence or purpose, I'm questioning *your* purposes; again, what would a Canadian dictionary provide that the major online dictionaries do not?

Comment: @choster - my purpose is to have a complete reference for Canadian English for whatever purpose it may serve. I think the more general dictionaries you are referring to just mention a small and probably more popular  part of the Canadian/Australian terms or expressions.

Comment: *behind* a paywall

Comment: Your best bet is to look up the word or expression in a dictionary  and see if it's BrEng, AusEng, or AmEng. Canadian English spelling I believe follows that of BrEng. Failing that enclose the expression with speech marks and search for a Canada domain

Comment: @Mari-LouA -     “*The site currently operates under a partial paywall model, where the majority of its content is made publicly available at no cost to readers.*” https://dictionary.cambridge.org/it/dizionario/inglese/paywall

Comment: "Under a paywall" sounds a bit weird to me, see https://www.dictionary.com/browse/paywall and here https://www.authorea.com/users/8850/articles/124254-10-famous-articles-still-behind-a-paywall

Comment: @Mari-LouA - yes, thanks for the suggestion...,so the answer to my question is..there is no free online Canadian English dictionary,  I suppose.

Comment: I agree with @Mari-LouA - “operating under a model” is not the same thing as “behind a paywall”.

Comment: You just added a quote of a close reason. Did you have a question that was closed? If so, please edit to add a link to that question.

Comment: @Mitch - there are CVs on this question for the stated reason. I’d like to understand if this question  is off-topic here on Meta. That’s it.

Comment: @user240918 Wait, so you added something to your question here on meta something about the question itself? That's awfully confusing. Shouldn't you just comment to that effect?

Comment: Forget that though, I get it. I can't read minds, but I suspect that the people who voted to close for that reason here on meta for some reason don't realize that requests for resources are off-topic on main but entirely on-topic on meta (however weird that might seem). Or maybe they have some other reason, but I just can't seem to imagine it right now.

Comment: @JJJ - how does that answer my question?

Comment: @user240918 you are asking for reference works on English. If I understand correctly, the consensus is that such references are given in that thread so it's easiest to find by those looking for them.

Comment: @JJJ - I am specifically asking for free online Canadian English reference, which is not mentioned, as far as I can tell, in that post. Plus that post is not meant to be a definitive one.

Comment: @user067531 and should you want to promote the fact that you are looking for such resources, then I suggest making a meta post (possibly this one), aimed at that: promotion. It's not a good idea to have those sources spread out over different questions if the consensus is to put them centrally. Now, you may get a nice answer but others who just look there will probably miss out. By the way, Mari's suggestions are also covered by that thread, Sven's aren't, I think.

Comment: @chenmunka - where can I find the answer to my question in the supposed original question? Thanks

Comment: @jimmi101 - where can I find the answer to my question in the supposed original question? Thanks

Comment: @JJJ - the fact the Sven’s suggestion is not in the  supposed original question means that the list is not complete and that this is not a duplicate. Close voting should not be a brainless activity.

Comment: @user067531 please consider [the last paragraph of this Meta answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10844/387405). Should duplicate questions on Meta sites still be unclear, please specify carefully why your question is fundamentally different and not a subset of what's asked in the target question. Also, try to keep insults to a minimum, while I won't take offense, they do make discourse less friendly.

Comment: Sven's suggestion would be an inappropriate addition to the list of general resources because it is only available in snippet form online. The truth of the matter is that you forgot about that page until I mentioned it several hours later in a comment which I self deleted when I posted an answer.

Comment: @Mari-LouA - ok if you think this is a duplicate please remove your answer, I’ll ask Sven to remove his so that I can remove my question.

Comment: So you can *delete* the question? Even if I'm on the fence as to whether it is a duplicate or not, I think it's still useful to the community.

Comment: @Mari-LouA -as a duplicate nobody will bother to read...

Comment: Not true, many a time I have stumbled on a duplicate question and found their answers to be useful.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the *Dictionary of Canadianisms on Historical Principles*, which Mari-Lou A mentions and links to in her answer, you may occasionally find Margery Fee & Janice McAlpine, [*[Oxford] Guide to Canadian English Usage*](https://books.google.com/books?id=aRUkAQAAMAAJ&dq=editions:ghL6L9ZtFOYC) helpful. The second edition (2007) is available in searchable snippet view only—but that may be enough in some instances.

For instance, a search for the word "hospital" yields [three snippet matches](https://books.google.com/books?id=aRUkAQAAMAAJ&dq=editions%3AghL6L9ZtFOYC&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=hospital), including this one:

> Five youths clad in just T-shirts and sweat pants were **in hospital** yesterday after police found them running around in the snow in -20 C temperatures. [—]*Province* (Vancouver) 26 Nov. 1990: 6

Although the quotation appears in the context of a discussion of whether Canadian English accepts *clad* as an alternative to *clothed* as a past participle of the verb *clothe*, it is at least circumstantially relevant to the question of whether Canadians say "go to hospital" because typical US English usage would (I believe) have included a definite article between "in" and "hospital" here:

> ...were in **the** hospital yesterday...

In any event, Fee & McAlpine is a serious and useful work—and it is available online in a limited form that permits snippet searches.

Answer (score 1):

[TERMIUM Plus®](http://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2alpha/alpha-eng.html?lang=eng)

> The Government of Canada’s terminology and linguistic data bank.
>   TERMIUM Plus®, one of the largest terminology and linguistic data banks in the world, gives you access to millions of terms in English, French, Spanish and Portuguese. You can find terms, abbreviations, definitions and usage examples in a wide range of specialized fields. The data bank is an essential tool for understanding an acronym, checking an official title, finding an equivalent in another language, and much more.

and

> **[A Dictionary of Canadianisms on Historical Principles](http://www.dchp.ca/dchp2/)**
>   As an historical dictionary, this work shows changes in the meanings of words over time, using dated quotations to illustrate these shifts. Thus, DCHP-2 includes words that have become outdated or obsolete and lists for the sake of historical completeness words and meanings that are considered offensive or derogatory today. These words, however, are clearly marked.

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn’t appear to be a dictionary in the common sense. Idioms, saying usage etc.

Comment: It aspires to be the equivalent of Mitford Mathews's great _A Dictionary of Americanisms on Historical Principles_ (1951)—which is to say that it is essentially a dictionary of words that have meanings peculiar to all or part of the country in question. I have the first edition of the _Dictionary of Canadianisms_ and find that it is not as comprehensive as I might wish; for example, it has no discussion of "go to hospital" (the subject of a recent EL&U question), which I believe is a common phrasing in Canadian English. Still it's a useful resource for (some) quirky Canadian regionalisms.

Comment: @SvenYargs - that question brought me here.